# Angularjs $http post not sending file object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm a newbie to Angularjs and I've been trying to upload the file submitted through a form. I was able to get the file object to a variable by using custom directive, but I'm not able to send the file object through $http post method.

I've tried the below.

```
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("file", file, file.name);

 var config = {
               headers : { 'Content-Type' : undefined },
               data: formData,
               transformRequest: function(data) {
                     return formData;
                }
              };

 $http.post(endPointUrl, formData, config).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
```

Can someone please help me in notifying where I'm going wrong and guide me to achieve this.

I'm using angularjs 1.5.5 and chrome 63.0

Comment: what is `file`?

Comment: the post format is `$http.post(url, data, headers)`, change it so that you will have data and config separately

Comment: File object created by form input-type 'file' holding properties like name, size, type, lastModifiedDate.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, I was referring Angular API docs in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. I tried setting $http.post(url,data,config) and $http.post(url, config) neither of them worked. I couldn't see shortcut method with headers. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SubashKunjupillai maybe you are talking about old syntax `$http({url:"...", method:"POST", ...})`, but the post method you are using has only one version: [`post(url, data, [config])`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, I tried with new API also like $http.post(url, data, config). It didn't work for me yet..

Comment: How about using `$http({method : 'POST', url : 'url', data : data, headers: { 'Content-Type' : undefined}}).then(function(response){ })` ?

Comment: And in my case, when I append file to form data, the code like this. First, append file to `FormData()` like `var fd = new FormData();  fd.append("file", files[0]);`. And using this code `$http({method: 'POST', url: 'url', data: fd,  transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }`